# What is the function in Jquery to keep special characters like " '

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

`Jquery` attribute contents a paragraph which has " ' sings. When i want to `alert` it output contents only up to first " sing in the paragraph. others are missing. why and how to avoid that. In `php` i solved it using `htmlspecialchars` function. What is the function in `Jquery` to do it?

**updates** : The attribute values comes from mysql database. 
sample string as follows

`One person height is 5'5" the other one is 12" less then him.`

```
<div id="dataview" class="col-md-9">

    </div>
```

```js
 $(window).load(function() {
   $.ajax({
     url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + 'main/data',
     dataType: "JSON",
     type: "POST",
     success: function(retdata) {
       $.each(retdata, function(i) {
         var content = '<div class="target btn-default" prop-content="' + retdata[i].content + '">' + retdata[i].content;
         $("#dataview").append(content);
       });
     }
   });
 });
 //Using event delegate   
 $(function() {
   $("#dataview").on('click', ".target", function() {
     var prop = $(this).attr("prop-content");
     alert(prop);

   });
 });
```

Comment: You don't need to.  Show us your code that sets the attribute.

Comment: @SLaks please see the updates

Comment: **Show us your code that sets the attribute. **  You should never create unescaped HTML in Javascript.

Comment: @SLaks please see the updates

Comment: @ahoffner: No; that isn't his problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should never concatenate strings into HTML text.  In fact, you also have an XSS vulnerability.

Instead, use safe Javascript APIs:

```
$('<div />', {class: "target btn-default", "prop-content": retdata[i]})
```